Unreal Engine Import Warning "The following bones are missing from the bind pose"
Problem
I'm receiving the following message while importing the character from mixamo.com. It does not happen for all characters but in some of them.

The following bones are missing from the bind pose:
mixamorig:HeadTop_End
mixamorig:LeftHandThumb4
mixamorig:LeftHandIndex4
mixamorig:LeftHandMiddle4
mixamorig:LeftHandRing4
mixamorig:LeftHandPinky4
mixamorig:RightHandThumb4
mixamorig:RightHandIndex4
mixamorig:RightHandMiddle4
mixamorig:RightHandRing4
mixamorig:RightHandPinky4
mixamorig:LeftToe_End
mixamorig:RightToe_End
This can happen for bones that are not vert-weighted. If they are not
in the correct orientation after importing, please set the "Use T0 as
ref pose" option or add them to the bind pose and reimport the
skeletal mesh.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Solution

The Error is general
I've seen other people receiving the same message for their case as well
The bone names can be changed depending on the skeleton

To solve this, you just need to select the:
Use T0 as ref pose
option while you're importing the FBX file. That will import flawlessly!
ℹ️ By the way "Use T0 as ref pose" option is under the Advanced section.

